# Shuffle array with a repeatable/predictable result based on a seed integer

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle, random-seed

I have 6 users and I want to shuffle an array for each user but with a particular logic.

I have array like this:

```
$a = array(1, 6, 8);
```

When shuffled it gives me these results:

```
shuffle($a); //array(8,6,1) or array(8,1,6) or ...
```

I want to shuffle the array for a specific user and have it be the same every time for that user:

- for `user` that has id equals 1, give array like this array(6,8,1) every time
- for `user` that has id equals 2, give array like this array(1,8,6) every time

In other words, I want to shuffle an array with private key!

Comment: Shuffle is random. Where does your specific ordering come from?

Comment: There are only 6 different orderings of that array, but you have 10 users. So some will have to have the same ordering.

Comment: There is no logic in case of array_suffle it will give you all random result

Comment: So save the order you want as a column in the db table?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in detail how a given user ID should result in a certain order. The logic behind it is not obvious from your examples.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. If the list always have `3` entries, there are `6` ways to permute them (including the original order). You can generate the list of permutations and then use the user ID to always pick the same entry from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a seed to the random number generator it will randomize the same way for the same seed (see the version differences below).  So use the *user id* as the seed:

```
srand(1);
shuffle($a);
```

**Output for 7.1.0 - 7.2.4**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 6
)
```

**Output for 4.3.0 - 5.6.30, 7.0.0 - 7.0.29**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 8
)
```

> **Note**: As of PHP 7.1.0, srand() has been made an alias of mt_srand().

This [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f535d6a44b4b82685974c2947db9343e9971e49f) should always produce the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting php.net:

> This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.

Whatever you are trying to get as a result, you cannot use shuffle because it will randomly give you some order.

If you want to randomly do an order to array, based on some criteria use usort:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
}
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

Now get the logic in the cmp function...